# Let $V$ be a $C$ vector space and $P ∈\operatorname{ End}(V )$ with $P^k = 0$ , we call such a map nilpotent.

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm still studying for my Linear Algebra exam, and this question is in one of the test exams. I missed the lecture when nilpotent was mentioned, and have not come across it before, so I got som trouble figuring out this one.

Let $V$ be a $C$ vector space and $P ∈ \operatorname{End}(V )$ with $P^k = 0$ , we call such a map nilpotent.

a) Give an example of such a linear map P that is not the zero map.

My teacher's answer: $A :\Bbb  C^2 → \Bbb C^2$ via the matrix $\begin{pmatrix} 0& 1\\ 0 &0 \end{pmatrix}$, (Don't know how to make a matrix in here, it is suppose to be a matrix with row 1 (0,1) and row 2 (0,0)) then $A^2 = 0$.

Even with the hint I don't understand. I have a Theorem about "Matrix of a nilpotent operator", so I understand why my teacher pick the matrix that he does, and I understand that we can chose the dimensional to be 2, therefore the matrix is a 2x2 matrix – right?

But then what is A? And weren't we supposed to find a map that wasn't zero?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well this $A$ is the operator that you want

$A$ is a matrix then is a linear transformation so $A \in End(\mathbb{C}^2)$

$A \not= 0$

And $A^2 = 0$

(In this example, $A = P$ and $k=2$)

Comment: Ah okay, so A is the exsample of a nilpotent linear map, which is not 0 (A=P), but as the question said $P^k$ $= 0 =$ $A^k$

Comment: Exaclty! You are right

Answer (score 0):

Any matrix that is either lower or upper triangular with zeros on the diagonal is nilpotent. This includes $$A=\begin{pmatrix}0  & 1 \\ 0 & 0\end{pmatrix}.$$

As for the question why a matrix? Because a matrix is an endomorphism (if you identify $\mathbb{C}^2\simeq \mathrm{M}_{2,1}(\mathbb{C}$)), $A:\mathbb{C}^2 \to \mathbb{C}^2,\, (z_1,z_2)\mapsto A(z_1,z_2)$.

If you don't like matrices, you could replace $A$ by the linear map it represents, namely $f(z_1,z_2)=(z_2,0)$ in this case. Then $f^2=0$.

Comment: I'm getting a little insecure on how to compute $f^2$ from $f(z_1 , z_2) = (z_2 , 0)$